# how can I get my sound design work to american companies?

Tags: design, portfolio

I'm a student in the last year and i have some good videos online with sound design made by me, how can i get my sound design videos/portfolio to american companies?

These are my sites.

http://www.behance.net/TiagoCardososound
http://soundfoley.wordpress.com/

Thank You

Comment: Since it looks like your in Portugal, you might want to try and get into the British/London market first. Unless your extremely talented and have a reel to prove it I think the time difference is usually enough of a deterrent to really have much of a shot when starting out.

Answer (score 3):

By knowing people who work in said American companies (esp. in marketing).

By interning/working in an audio (post) production house that does a lot of the productions that you're interested in.

By knowing freelancers that do said productions and getting them to hand you some of their work (e.g. editing) and forming a partnership that way.

By establishing yourself as a freelancer (very difficult).

Prepare to compete a lot.